# How to set header search path? Xcode, C++, Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm trying to learn C++ using Xcode however the line `#include "Sales_item.h"` produces an error. Both files are in the same directory which is the project open in Xcode. I cannot figure out how to set the header search path in Xcode which may be the problem. Here is all of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main()
{
    Sales_item book;
    std::cin >> book;
    std::cout << book << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Sales_item const&)", referenced from:
  "operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Sales_item&)", referenced from:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: the error is definitely from the line I mentioned and it is not a typo error I have been trying to figure this out for many hours

Comment: This seem to be a linker error, where the linker is looking for `operator<<` for `Sales_item`. From this part of the code it is hard to tell why it  cannot find it (unless, of course, you haven't implemented it yet or forgot to add the source file to the project).

Comment: What is a linker? How do I implement the file? The file is in the project

Comment: these are the contents of the folder which is open in xcode, the latter containing the code I wrote in the question: Sales_item.h main.cpp

Comment: A linker is a program that pulls together several compiled files and builds the program file from those. It tries to fix things like calling a function in another file. "Implement" just means "to write the code". :-) One way to get your problem is to use a function or operator that you haven't written yet. But there are many other ways: [What is an undefined reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Ok so how do I get the linker within Xcode to pull the file Sales_item.h?